# how to use emplace_back to insert a new element into a vector of vector?

Tags: c++

I'm confused by the syntax of some C++ concepts.

Let's say I have a vector of vector:

```
vector<vector<int>> data;
```

I can use `push_back()` to insert a new element:

```
data.push_back({1, 1});
```

In this way, I list initialized a new element, then a copy of this element is pushed to `data`?

I can also do it in this way:

```
vector<int> tmp{1, 1};
data.emplace_back(tmp);
```

But if I directly call `emplace()`, like in this way:

```
data.emplace_back(1, 1);
```

It does not give me the expected result.

Did I misunderstand something here?

---update:
sorry, what I mean is `emplace_back`. My question is how to initialize directly using `emplace_back` instead of initializing a tmp vector first, `vector<int> tmp{1, 1};`.

Comment: `emplace` and `emplace_back` are two different functions, so what result did you expect in the second snippet?

Comment: Your title asks how to use `emplace_back`, but in your question you seem to know how to use that and are asking about [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace).  Can you clarify?

Comment: Note: This is a good idea for a question, but the question itself needs work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can use push_back to insert a new element: data.push_back({1, 1}); In this way, I list initialized a new element, then a copy of this element is pushed to data?

exactly.

> data.emplace(1, 1);

`vector<Type>::emplace_back` forwards its arguments to the constructor of `Type`. Now, `std::vector<int>` has a constructor that takes two integer arguments! The one specifying length (1) and fill element (1).

You can, however, inform the compiler you *actually* mean list initialization!

```
#include "fmt/format.h"
#include "fmt/ranges.h"
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>
int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> a;
  a.emplace_back(std::initializer_list<int>{1, 1});
  a.emplace_back(std::initializer_list<int>{2, 2});
  fmt::print("{}\n", fmt::join(a.begin(), a.end(), ";"));
}
```

yields the expected

```
 {1, 1};{2, 2}
```

To show it really does the in-place construction: Follow this [link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgCspAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcVyJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BAVU1AnUNBEUR0bEJtvWNzTltwz2hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1CYbbqHpYngAXrEA%2BrR4CgSH2CYaAIKb27uYB0cAbtVExEezzer3eDB2Xn25jMVBYBAA9PxiCwmAQAHQIaHAsEQqFmGFw%2BHEQzATAKDFY16hAh7FGhCBzA4Adisrz27L293QIBAfwcJEObi5PL5AMF1KBG2weyYh1ZIJeHJlaKSXgUCCuUSYyAA1hATCyNqQjUaDQAROZy7FsjlMNGYFhJAyrTXavXCkAnRxnS7EG53B5HCVSg0WLikPZcc2WjbypV2h1O7WYV26iAer14H3XW73cWCIEsgJ7MzRq2gm3s2EEHlJYjU/X40PmkzxNwMaER6s87Soel2mLAekLZWuBkRrGx6FzGPy80cBa0TjxXh%2BDhaUioThuazWTlLFZfTY8Ug19cLhY6kDxDT6TiSVeaXhbji8BQgW9nrQLOCwGCIFBUEdOhYnISg0GA%2Bg4mALguACGhaAIWJ3wgKIn1IKJQgaABPTgTwgthBAAeQYWhcPPUgsBRIxxAo/BiH%2BPA/nfCjMFUaovCQvDeGpTAlwo24omJYhsI8LB0IIesWG4hYqAMYAFAANTwTAAHciKSRhuJkQQRDEdgpB0%2BQlDUdDdHDAwjBQXdLH0PAonfWBmDYEBq1IP44g4JkNG/BZUCSRwBBYgBaIiNj2YKuUOM1TEsawuCZN8%2BMY5wIFcUY/HDYIphKMo9BSNJAsyTwWny/Iit6XLZlsZKOgYLoRhKnJw3aIqGsmYp%2BnKIZugyvR7m6SquokBYFAPVY9EkzA1h4Rdl0fCiX1UAAOAA2YLVskPZgGQZBIy4NEzD2CAdzi2y9lwQgSAOMwNnDPYPEg2IbruuZeC/C9SCvG87w4B9SGk1aDo2SRVturgNniZaNlusxVtW0g1w3F83w/U8nx/f8ICQJYCFVAgwIgCCkhA7rMHwAE9H4XTRHEQzqeMlR1Ao1TiSSGTfpXRH0JfIjOPxvZUCoPYVvWzbtt2/bDuOx6Sagl6uDe9HzxnUgEEwJgsDicd%2BP%2B6T4jRGGNEkSGNg0aGTckDQmUSJHn04VHPwx0hfwAtiOIBQmGgU5RDD4oQEFQVS13woC5dRDJfbCWgA6Du3SGJ0mQBguCE7D0m%2BeEQPg/Q93kBeYgFIdwJ2OQOp8DXXgGb0unpAZxQmbMvRLOMGybEExyoGc9g3I8zhvN8zcAoyEKwoiqKNhituErfcaDKGCuo/97OQ/ehiZt4VmmHZ7gF05hbkc4bBS8467RY2radr22DpZOtuI0ugEFaVj7Vd13hpI2DZDa/3%2B/7/7mi1i7vidirS815bz8Q2Afe2r5laD34mYGBm5i6vwWB5NIzhJBAA%3D%3D%3D) to gcc.godbolt.org, and observe how `push_back({3,3,3,3});` actually calls the `vector<int>` constructor and then the `insert` of the `vector<vector>`, while `emplace_back` really just calls the initializer-list constructor.

Comment: is there any fundamental difference between ```a.emplace_back(std::initializer_list<int>{1, 1});``` and ```a.push_back({1, 1});```?

Comment: yes, the first one creates the new vector in place, the second one creates a temporary one and copies it (or moves it, if copy elision works) there.

Answer (score -1):

There is an emplace function, but this takes an iterator ([see docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace)).

`emplace_back` will add a new element to the end of the vector.

`emplace` emplaces the element at a specified a position indicated by an iterator. `v.emplace_back(1)` and `v.emplace(v.end(), 1)` are the same, because the indicated position is the end of `v`.

[see this playground](https://godbolt.org/z/bKP3T9MqW)

Comment: sure, copying integers is cheap. What is *not* cheap is creating a vector, reallocating space for two elements, and deallocating space for the temporary vector. (I'm not sure how this answer addresses the question!)